# Unable to start Node.js application that uses ES module

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I have a simple Node.js `16.x` application. It uses ES modules, so I have `"type": "module"` in `package.json`. Everything works fine whenever I use `npm` scripts.

Now I'm trying to deploy it using Docker and I don't need the `npm` scripts anymore, so I'm starting the application directly using the `node` binary, in the same way I declared it within `package.json`: `node --require dotenv/config main.js` ...but that doesn't work, it fails with a typical error message around ES modules and such:

```sh
(node:9) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/opt/application/main.js:1
import { app } from "./application.js";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

I've also tried a combination of settings around this command: `node --input-type=module --experimental-modules --require dotenv/config main.js` by [following this guide](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#determining-module-system), but still, I'm getting the same error message.

I think I'm missing something trivial here, so my question is: how can I start this application without using `package.json` (because I won't have it anymore at this point) or renaming `.js` files to `.mjs`, by using only the `node` binary?

---

This is how the application looks like in the filesystem (if it makes any difference):

```sh
/opt/application # ls -ltr 
total 72
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2158 Oct 10 13:47 application.js
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 27 14:57 support
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           318 Jan 27 14:57 main.js
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 27 14:57 handler
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 27 14:57 config
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1448 Jan 27 14:58 knexfile.js
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 27 16:57 service
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 27 16:57 model
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         28672 Jan 27 16:57 production.sqlite3
drwxr-xr-x  228 root     root         12288 Jan 27 16:57 node_modules
/opt/application # cat main.js 
import { app } from "./application.js";
import { logger } from "./config/winston.js";
import { SERVER_PORT } from "./support/constants.js";

const port = process.env.PORT || SERVER_PORT;

app.listen(port, () => {
  logger.debug(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`);
  logger.info("Press CTRL-C to stop");
});
```

And this is (an excerpt) of the `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "node-express",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "nodemon --require dotenv/config src/server.js",
    "start": "node --require dotenv/config src/server.js",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "compression": "1.7.4",
    "dotenv": "10.0.0",
    "errorhandler": "1.5.1",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "helmet": "4.6.0",
    "http-status-codes": "2.1.4",
    "lusca": "1.7.0",
    "knex": "0.95.11",
    "morgan": "1.10.0",
    "objection": "2.2.16",
    "sqlite3": "5.0.2",
    "uuid": "8.3.2",
    "winston": "3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@jest/globals": "27.2.1",
    "cross-env": "7.0.3",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-recommended": "4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "24.4.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "jest": "27.2.1",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "nodemon": "2.0.12",
    "prettier": "2.4.1",
    "supertest": "6.1.6"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "clearMocks": true,
    "setupFiles": [
      "dotenv/config"
    ],
    "verbose": true
  },
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "ignore": [
      "*.test.js"
    ],
    "watch": [
      "src/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please put your package.json too in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're trying to do isn't possible. From the [Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/packages.html#packages_determining_module_system):

> Node.js will treat the following as ES modules when passed to node as
> the initial input, or when referenced by import statements within ES
> module code:
>
> - Files ending in `.mjs`.
> - Files ending in `.js` when the nearest parent `package.json` file contains a top-level `"type"` field with a value of `"module"`.
> - **Strings passed in as an argument to `--eval`, or piped to `node` via `STDIN`, with the flag `--input-type=module`.**

If possible, you should just copy over the `package.json` in your Dockerfile - that's what Node expects.

Otherwise, if you absolutely can't have a `package.json` in your Docker image, then `node --input-type module --require dotenv/config < main.js` should do the trick.

Comment: OK, that is...unfortunate. I end up renaming all the files into `.mjs`. I really don't see a point of including a `package.json` file in the release. Thanks for the help!